# Select where parent does not contain DOM in any generation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't figure this one out, and I may be making it harder than it is.

I need to select all DOMS with class 'B', whose parent, 'A', does not contain class 'C' in any generation, and 'C' is NOT a sibling of 'B'

Example:

We would not select B if

`A => ({B}, {D => ({C})})`

Because B's parent, A, also contains D, and D contains C.

However, we would select B if

`A => ({B}, {D => ({})})`

Because B's parent, A, does contain D, but C is nowhere in this particular tree under A.

I've tried:

`$('.B').not($(this).parent('.A').find('.C'))`

But the not statement here actually selects the 'C', and excludes C itself from the array of B. I also tried `has` instead of `find`, but that not only selects the parent A for exclusion, but I believe `has` only scans through one generation.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with what you have there, when you're calling `not`, `this` is not `.B` though.  You need to pass `not` a function.

```
$('.B').not(function(){
    return $(this).parent('.A').find('.C').length;
});
```

Comment: I should have figured... Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you have a fairly complex condition on whether an element should be included or not, I'd use the `filter`-function and supply a function to execute the logic:

```
$('.A > .B').filter( function () {
  return $(this).parent().find('.C').length === 0;
});
```